# Не выводится фрагмент c RecyclerView с фрагментами RecyclerView(android)

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, recyclerviewadapter

пытаюсь сделать что то похоже на это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но на телефоне вообще ничего не выводится, нет никакой ошибки, ничего. В чем может быть причина?

Класс одной задачи.

```
package com.example.projecttasks.TodayTasks;

public class Tasks_item {

    private String taskName;

    public Tasks_item(String TaskName){
        this.taskName = TaskName;
    }

    public String getTaskName() {
        return taskName;
    }
}
```

Адаптер с recyclerview в котором содержатся задачи.

```
package com.example.projecttasks.TodayTasks;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.projecttasks.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tasks_item_Recycler_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Tasks_item_Recycler_Adapter.RecyclerViewViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Tasks_item> arrayList;

    public  static  class  RecyclerViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView taskName;

        public RecyclerViewViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            taskName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_tasks);
        }
    }

    public Tasks_item_Recycler_Adapter(ArrayList<Tasks_item> arrayList){
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tasks_item, parent, false);
        RecyclerViewViewHolder recyclerViewViewHolder = new RecyclerViewViewHolder(view);
        return recyclerViewViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Tasks_item tasks_item = arrayList.get(position);
        holder.taskName.setText(tasks_item.getTaskName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
}
```

Фрагмент который содержит recycler view с задачами и имеет поля для название группы задач

```
package com.example.projecttasks.TodayTasks;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.projecttasks.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tasks_item_card extends Fragment {

    private String projectName;
    private RecyclerView itemRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    public Tasks_item_card(String projectName){
        this.projectName = projectName;
    }

    public String getProjectName() {
        return projectName;
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks_item_card, container, false);
        itemRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.tasks_item);
        itemRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        ArrayList<Tasks_item> recyclerTaskItem = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerTaskItem.add(new Tasks_item("Task 0"));
        recyclerTaskItem.add(new Tasks_item("Task 1"));
        recyclerTaskItem.add(new Tasks_item("Task 2"));
        recyclerTaskItem.add(new Tasks_item("Task 3"));
        adapter = new Tasks_item_Recycler_Adapter(recyclerTaskItem);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        itemRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        itemRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Адаптер recyclerview который содержит группы задач.

```
package com.example.projecttasks.TodayTasks;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.projecttasks.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tasks_Card_Recycler_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Tasks_Card_Recycler_Adapter.RecyclerViewViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Tasks_item_card> arrayList;

    public  static  class  RecyclerViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView projectName;

        public RecyclerViewViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            projectName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.project_name);
        }
    }

    public Tasks_Card_Recycler_Adapter(ArrayList<Tasks_item_card> arrayList){
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tasks_item_card, parent, false);
        RecyclerViewViewHolder recyclerViewViewHolder = new RecyclerViewViewHolder(view);
        return recyclerViewViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Tasks_item_card tasks_item_card = arrayList.get(position);
        holder.projectName.setText(tasks_item_card.getProjectName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

}
```

Фрагмент в котором лежит recyclerview с группами задач.

```
package com.example.projecttasks.TodayTasks;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.projecttasks.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tasks_item_list extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView cardRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks_item_card, container, false);
        cardRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.list_card);
        cardRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        ArrayList<Tasks_item_card> recyclerCardItem = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerCardItem.add(new Tasks_item_card("Project 0"));
        recyclerCardItem.add(new Tasks_item_card("Project 1"));
        recyclerCardItem.add(new Tasks_item_card("Project 2"));
        recyclerCardItem.add(new Tasks_item_card("Project 3"));
        adapter = new Tasks_Card_Recycler_Adapter(recyclerCardItem);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        cardRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        cardRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Основное активити в котором вызывается предыдущий фрагмент.

```
package com.example.projecttasks;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.projecttasks.TodayTasks.Tasks_item_list;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;


import android.view.MenuItem;

public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Tasks_item_list tasksToday;
    FragmentTransaction fTrans;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            fTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fTrans.add(R.id.main_fragment, tasksToday);
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_menu:

                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_today_tasks:

                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_calendar_tasks:

                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_tree_aim_tasks:

                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_settings:

                    return true;
            }
            fTrans.commit();
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        tasksToday = new Tasks_item_list();

    }

}
```

Comment: Старайтесь придерживаться правил именовая переменных и классов в Java. CamelCase используйте, подчёркивания - не используйте (они только для имён констант), иначе ваш код режет глаза и многие просто не станут его читать. По сути вопроса - попробуйте назначать layoutManager до установки адаптера.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за совет по поводу именования переменных и классов, учту)